# Handlebars.net Accessing collections with indexers

Tags: handlebars.net

In handlebars.net, I know we can access array members like

```
{{SomeArray.0}}
```

Is it possible to access collection items through indexers like

```
{{SomeCollectionInstance['key']}}
```

or

```
{{SomeCollectionInstance.key}}
```

If not possible, can anyone propose a way to implement it, at least for string and numeric indexers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dictionaries and objects, the `.keyName` or `.propertyName` notations are supported.

You can also use `.[key name]` or `.[property name]` (square brackets) - this is useful for situations where the property name has a weird character in it, like a space.

Comment: Thanks for the info but the actual question was accessing through indexers like 

`public object this[string fieldName]
{
 get
 {
  return fieldValue;
 }
}`

Any comments on this?

Comment: It is not supported for an arbitrary class. If the class implements IDictionary it would work.

Comment: Using IDictionary looks like a very good idea. Thanks for pointing this out.